# What are Maven coordinates of artefacts that contain Java EE and Spring XSDs and catalogs?

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee, xsd

I need to schema validate numerous Java EE and spring files. I would like my system to operate off-line as much as possible. For this, I would need a collection of all the official schema files, and ideally an XML catalog to resolve them.

I am pretty sure that they are in artefacts in maven central, but I would need the coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no formal Maven artefacts containing Java EE XSD Schema files.

You can download these from [Java EE: XML Schemas for Java EE Deployment Descriptors](http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/). If you're using any version of JBoss AS or WildFly then the individual schema files are also available as part of its distribution bundle.

Schema for Spring Framework configuration files are embedded in their respective jar files (and therefore are available in maven central).